# Facebook Graph API 2.0 creating Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala, koala-gem

According to facebook, as of April 30th 2014 the `create_event` method is no longer available which I assume means no ability to publish events?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> create_event is no longer available.

Is it still be possible using v1.0? (to be phased out April 30th, 2015).  I haven't been able to find any examples and I want to publish event on behalf of a facebook page.  Is this still possible?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/events

When I try it I get a depreciation warning and an impersonation for using a token for a page, but it also fails when I use my personal token.  Probably because I don't have the create_event permission (despite requesting it, it doesn't show up in the facebook token debugger)

```
Deprecation warning: The REST API is now deprecated; please use the equivalent Graph API methods instead.  See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/.
=> {"error_code"=>190,
 "error_msg"=>"Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API",
```

Permissions:

```
[{"permission"=>"installed", "status"=>"granted"},
 {"permission"=>"public_profile", "status"=>"granted"},
 {"permission"=>"manage_pages", "status"=>"granted"},
 {"permission"=>"publish_actions", "status"=>"granted"}]
```

Comment: It's all in the link you provided: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/events#publish

Comment: Try it in the Graph API Explorer using v1.0, and report back

Comment: Ok it works, problem was/is, only older apps can choose to use the previous API versions, if your app is newer than April 30th, you are forced to use v2.0.  Stopped using my test apps (which are new) and it started working

Comment: As of sometime in June, they've apparently shut off the ability to create events. My apps have started working. Queries that used to work in Graph explorer don't anymore. I think Facebook pulled the plug on it, without any alternatives.

Comment: Does anybody know if there will be any updates? Or is "without any alternatives" their last offer?

Answer (score 1):

Any application that has been active as a 1.0 application will still be able to create events until v1.0 is removed. If you just had a 1.0 application sitting around not doing anything, it probably lost the capability.

Example of an active app: Facebook for iOS can still create events.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a new API for managing events on behalf of a facebook page (still doesn't help for a personal profile).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events

Comment: I appreciate any answer after 9+ years!